# I want to add some textboxes on selecting option from select menu in my PHP Page. This should be Dynamically(without reloding page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On changing options from select menu the no of text boxes should be changed without reloading the page.

```
 <select id="options">
   <option >Select</option>
    <option value="first_div">first_div</option>
     <option value="second_div">second_div</option>
      <option value="third_div">third_div</option>
       <option value="fourth_div">fourth_div</option>
        <option value="fifth_div">fifth_div</option>
 </select>
```

I used following Sample Jquery code. on selecting any option it goes to display div.
But i want that if i select another option the another div should appears and previous should be removed.

`$(function()` `{
   var selector =` `{
    options : '#o1'`
   }
  `$('#options').bind('change', function()` `{ 
     var h = $(this).val();`
    `if (h)` `{ 
             $(selector[$(this).attr('id')]).find('> o1').each(function()` `{ 
                $(this).toggle(h == $(this).data('select-value'))`
                 `.attr('disabled', (h != $(this).data('select-value')));`
           `});`
          `$(selector[$(this).attr('id')]).find('option:visible').eq(0).attr('selected', true);`
            `$(selector[$(this).attr('id')]).show();`
        }
   `});`
 });`

Comment: Ok, good luck? I'm not seeing any question. nor PHP for that matter.

Comment: Should we code for you?

Comment: this would need javascript not php

Comment: @PatrickEvans is right try some javascript and then post it here if you still can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Its working to me..

`$(function() {`
   `var selector = {`
   `options : '#o1'`
 `}`
  `$('#options').bind('change', function() {`
   `var h = $(this).val();`
    `if (h) {`
          `$(selector[$(this).attr('id')]).find('> o1').each(function() {`
               `$(this).toggle(h == $(this).data('select-value'))`
                  `.attr('disabled', (h != $(this).data('select-value')));`
          `});`
            `$(selector[$(this).attr('id')]).find('option:visible').eq(0).attr('selected', true);`
            `$(selector[$(this).attr('id')]).show();
        }`
   `});`
`});`